# Set up the absolute url with phpmyadmin on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, dns, ubuntu-16.04

I have set up phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu and it can work successfully. And I also set up the domain name to the same IP address.
Now, both of this two different domain name :
**example.com

foo.example.com**
can implement phpMyAdmin.
But I want only one of them work with phpMyAdmin.

I have browsed the document of phpMyAdmin [here](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_PmaAbsoluteUri), to set up the absolute url with phpMyAdmin, just modify **$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']** variable.
But in my configuration file, this variable is not exist.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the DNS CNAME entry for foo.example.com from your domain's DNS zone if you don't want this subdomain to be active.